# React-Admin installation error: Has no exported member 'CombinedState'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-admin

I have installed `react-admin` with `npm` and after the build,
 
I get this error:

`node_modules/redux/index: has no exported member 'CombinedState'.  TS2694`

and it's linked to the file:

```js
declare const _default: import("redux").Reducer<import("redux").CombinedState<{
   resources: any;
   customQueries: any;
   loading: any;
   notifications: any;
   references: any;
   ui: any;
}>, import("redux").AnyAction>;
```

There is no `CombinedState` in the `redux`, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This sounds like a troubleshooting issue.

But first a quick dive in to understand where `CombinedState` is originating from,
and I'll base my explanation off actual files.

1. Within `...\node_modules\redux\index.d.ts [lines 35-56]`,
   you'll notice that `CombinedState` is actually a `type` declared within `redux`.
   And indeed, it's actually exported!
2. Also note that all the `reducer` functionality used by `react-admin` is defined within `ra-core`,
   a package upon which `react-admin` depends.

Within `ra-core`, inspect folders `...\esm\reducer`  and `...\lib\reducer`, that's where this line:

```js
import("redux").CombinedState
```

is used mostly - meaning that `CombinedState` is being imported.

**Possible Solutions:**

- First, please confirm that your `react-admin` and `redux` installations aren't corrupted.
  It might not have occured to you, but I have often had to re-install packages due to this.
- Check that the `redux` version in use corresponds with the `react-admin` you're using.
  The best way to verify is to look at the `package.json` file within the [react-admin demo](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/package.json).
  Since it works, all must be fine, right!?

These suggestions are based off, working with `react-admin v3.2.1`.
Please let us know what helped you. Thanks.